# Hiccup in the site

Tags: bug, reputation

I have two questions this morning with a positive score, yet neither the app or full site achievement drop downs are reflecting and rep changes after half an hour.

Neither answer is showing up in the "all actions" section either.

There appears to be a holdup somewhere.

Comment: I'm getting this too. My rep increases, but the achievements stream and icon don't reflect the change, so I have no idea where it's coming from.

Comment: @Bathsheba I don't understand how that's related.